# set the constant width between 2 objects in a forEach loop

Tags: swift, foreach, autolayout, var, addition

I want my swift code to space each imageview by 5 percent of the view controller width. So imageview a is the first 10 percent of the width then a 5 percent gap then another imageview with 10 percent width followed by 5 percent gap. You can see what I am looking for in the image below. Right now my code is not compiling with the error at  smith += self.view.widthAnchor * 0.05. All code is below.

[image]

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var box1 = UIImageView();var box2 = UIImageView();var box3 = UIImageView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var smith : Double = 0
        [box1,box2,box3].forEach{
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.backgroundColor = .red
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            
        
            $0.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: CGFloat(smith)).isActive = true
            $0.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true

            $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.1).isActive = true
            $0.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 0.1).isActive = true
            
            
            smith += self.view.widthAnchor * 0.05

        }
        print(smith)
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Use a stack view

Comment: I agree that a stack view might be best, but here's a second thought - while setting **most** constraints in `viewDidLoad` work best (even in a custom `init`) - frames (like screen width aren't yet available. Learn the view and view controller life cycle and (1) set your spacers - be they views or constants/multipliers of constraints - later when iOS has determined the screen size, and then (2) work inside the life cycle for orientation changes... you *do* realize that all devices have a different width if in landscape/portrait.

Comment: @dfd can you provide your suggestion as a answer i will give you credit for it.

Comment: @RobertCrabtree can you provide your suggestion as a answer i will give you credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. Which approach to use would depend on what else you're planning on doing with your app and these image views.

One easy method is to use a `UIStackView`.

Since each image view will be 10% of the width of the view, and we want the spacing between them to be 5% the width of the view:

```
10% + 5% + 10% + 5% + 10% == 40%
```

so we know the stack view should be 40% of the width of the view, with its Distribution set to `Equal Spacing`.

Here is example code:

```
class BoxesViewController: UIViewController {
    let box1 = UIImageView()
    let box2 = UIImageView()
    let box3 = UIImageView()
    
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // stack view properties
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
        
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        [box1,box2,box3].forEach {
            
            stackView.addArrangedSubview($0)
            
            $0.backgroundColor = .red
            
            // make the image views square (1:1 ratio ... height == width)
            $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: $0.widthAnchor).isActive = true
            
            // each image view is 10% of the width of the view
            $0.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.10).isActive = true
            
        }
        
        // we want spacing between the image views to be 5% of teh width of the view
        // so...
        //  10% + 5% + 10% + 5% + 10% == 40%
        stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.40).isActive = true
        
        // let's constrain the stack view 20-pts from the top (respecting safe area)
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
        // zero pts from leading
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

and, if we rotate the device, we still get 10% image views and 5% spacing:

[image]